# FFmpeg quality setting for subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

This is a general question, but is such thing exist? I burned .ass full-styled subtitle to a .mp4 video, the quality of burned subtitle is reduced in the output video, ex: the border of the text is blurred.

The command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "ass=subtitle.ass" output.mp4
```

Output:

```
>ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "ass=subtitle.ass" output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-73010-gbb3703a Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 37.100 / 56. 37.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 17.100 /  5. 17.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : PotEncoder
  Duration: 00:01:17.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1159 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [
SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1026 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 63507 tbn, 59.94 tbc (defaul
t)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 03b938c0] Added subtitle file: 'subtitle.ass' (5 styles, 24 even
ts)
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] 264 - core 146 r2538 121396c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Cop
yleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb
lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 m
e_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro
ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 i
nterlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenec
ut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=
0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.37.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 6
40x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 63507 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100
Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libvo_aacenc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libvo_aacenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   53 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=      55kB time=00:00:01.79 bitrate= 248.9kbits/
frame=   75 fps= 73 q=29.0 size=     158kB time=00:00:02.54 bitrate= 508.7kbits/
frame=   95 fps= 61 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.19 bitrate= 657.4kbits/
frame=  115 fps= 54 q=29.0 size=     368kB time=00:00:03.86 bitrate= 779.2kbits/
frame=  132 fps= 50 q=29.0 size=     467kB time=00:00:04.44 bitrate= 861.0kbits/
frame=  149 fps= 48 q=29.0 size=     576kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 943.9kbits/
frame=  166 fps= 46 q=29.0 size=     680kB time=00:00:05.55 bitrate=1002.4kbits/
frame=  182 fps= 44 q=29.0 size=     796kB time=00:00:06.09 bitrate=1069.8kbits/
frame=  197 fps= 42 q=29.0 size=     925kB time=00:00:06.60 bitrate=1147.3kbits/
frame=  213 fps= 41 q=29.0 size=    1033kB time=00:00:07.13 bitrate=1185.6kbits/
frame=  230 fps= 40 q=29.0 size=    1157kB time=00:00:07.69 bitrate=1231.3kbits/
frame=  245 fps= 39 q=29.0 size=    1261kB time=00:00:08.20 bitrate=1259.1kbits/
frame=  260 fps= 38 q=29.0 size=    1364kB time=00:00:08.71 bitrate=1281.5kbits/
frame=  275 fps= 37 q=29.0 size=    1479kB time=00:00:09.20 bitrate=1316.3kbits/
frame=  289 fps= 37 q=29.0 size=    1597kB time=00:00:09.66 bitrate=1352.9kbits/
frame=  305 fps= 36 q=29.0 size=    1731kB time=00:00:10.20 bitrate=1389.7kbits/
frame=  322 fps= 36 q=29.0 size=    1829kB time=00:00:10.78 bitrate=1389.0kbits/
frame=  338 fps= 36 q=29.0 size=    1945kB time=00:00:11.31 bitrate=1407.9kbits/
frame=  354 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    2084kB time=00:00:11.85 bitrate=1440.6kbits/
frame=  370 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    2214kB time=00:00:12.38 bitrate=1464.1kbits/
frame=  388 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    2336kB time=00:00:12.96 bitrate=1475.9kbits/
frame=  404 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    2443kB time=00:00:13.50 bitrate=1482.2kbits/
frame=  422 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    2584kB time=00:00:14.10 bitrate=1500.7kbits/
frame=  439 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    2702kB time=00:00:14.68 bitrate=1507.3kbits/
frame=  455 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    2818kB time=00:00:15.21 bitrate=1516.8kbits/
frame=  471 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    2930kB time=00:00:15.75 bitrate=1523.4kbits/
frame=  489 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    3047kB time=00:00:16.35 bitrate=1525.9kbits/
frame=  507 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    3153kB time=00:00:16.93 bitrate=1525.1kbits/
frame=  525 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    3246kB time=00:00:17.54 bitrate=1516.1kbits/
frame=  544 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    3353kB time=00:00:18.19 bitrate=1509.7kbits/
frame=  563 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    3478kB time=00:00:18.81 bitrate=1514.2kbits/
frame=  583 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    3590kB time=00:00:19.49 bitrate=1508.6kbits/
frame=  600 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    3710kB time=00:00:20.04 bitrate=1515.9kbits/
frame=  614 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    3818kB time=00:00:20.51 bitrate=1524.8kbits/
frame=  629 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    3949kB time=00:00:21.02 bitrate=1538.9kbits/
frame=  645 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4075kB time=00:00:21.55 bitrate=1548.5kbits/
frame=  661 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4193kB time=00:00:22.09 bitrate=1554.9kbits/
frame=  680 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4315kB time=00:00:22.71 bitrate=1555.9kbits/
frame=  700 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4423kB time=00:00:23.39 bitrate=1548.9kbits/
frame=  719 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4527kB time=00:00:24.01 bitrate=1543.8kbits/
frame=  738 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4632kB time=00:00:24.64 bitrate=1539.5kbits/
frame=  758 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4747kB time=00:00:25.31 bitrate=1535.7kbits/
frame=  774 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4857kB time=00:00:25.85 bitrate=1539.0kbits/
frame=  790 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    4967kB time=00:00:26.38 bitrate=1541.9kbits/
frame=  807 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    5108kB time=00:00:26.96 bitrate=1551.6kbits/
frame=  825 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    5223kB time=00:00:27.54 bitrate=1553.1kbits/
frame=  842 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    5344kB time=00:00:28.12 bitrate=1556.4kbits/
frame=  861 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    5489kB time=00:00:28.75 bitrate=1563.7kbits/
frame=  879 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    5596kB time=00:00:29.36 bitrate=1561.3kbits/
frame=  897 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    5705kB time=00:00:29.96 bitrate=1559.7kbits/
frame=  914 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    5810kB time=00:00:30.52 bitrate=1559.6kbits/
frame=  929 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    5914kB time=00:00:31.03 bitrate=1561.1kbits/
frame=  946 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    6033kB time=00:00:31.58 bitrate=1564.6kbits/
frame=  961 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    6154kB time=00:00:32.10 bitrate=1570.6kbits/
frame=  976 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=    6281kB time=00:00:32.58 bitrate=1578.8kbits/
frame=  991 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    6396kB time=00:00:33.09 bitrate=1582.9kbits/
frame= 1007 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    6496kB time=00:00:33.63 bitrate=1582.2kbits/
frame= 1021 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    6575kB time=00:00:34.09 bitrate=1579.6kbits/
frame= 1038 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    6662kB time=00:00:34.67 bitrate=1573.8kbits/
frame= 1054 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    6767kB time=00:00:35.21 bitrate=1574.3kbits/
frame= 1069 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    6834kB time=00:00:35.69 bitrate=1568.1kbits/
frame= 1086 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    6932kB time=00:00:36.25 bitrate=1566.2kbits/
frame= 1103 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7015kB time=00:00:36.83 bitrate=1560.1kbits/
frame= 1121 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7104kB time=00:00:37.44 bitrate=1554.3kbits/
frame= 1137 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7176kB time=00:00:37.97 bitrate=1548.1kbits/
frame= 1157 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7255kB time=00:00:38.64 bitrate=1537.7kbits/
frame= 1171 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7315kB time=00:00:39.11 bitrate=1532.1kbits/
frame= 1184 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7377kB time=00:00:39.53 bitrate=1528.7kbits/
frame= 1204 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7478kB time=00:00:40.20 bitrate=1523.7kbits/
frame= 1224 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7566kB time=00:00:40.87 bitrate=1516.3kbits/
frame= 1238 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7651kB time=00:00:41.34 bitrate=1516.1kbits/
frame= 1253 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7763kB time=00:00:41.82 bitrate=1520.4kbits/
frame= 1270 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    7890kB time=00:00:42.40 bitrate=1524.0kbits/
frame= 1286 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8012kB time=00:00:42.94 bitrate=1528.3kbits/
frame= 1300 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8147kB time=00:00:43.40 bitrate=1537.5kbits/
frame= 1317 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8267kB time=00:00:43.96 bitrate=1540.5kbits/
frame= 1332 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8365kB time=00:00:44.47 bitrate=1540.8kbits/
frame= 1347 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8470kB time=00:00:44.98 bitrate=1542.4kbits/
frame= 1365 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8573kB time=00:00:45.56 bitrate=1541.2kbits/
frame= 1383 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8706kB time=00:00:46.17 bitrate=1544.6kbits/
frame= 1398 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8797kB time=00:00:46.68 bitrate=1543.7kbits/
frame= 1414 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    8905kB time=00:00:47.21 bitrate=1544.9kbits/
frame= 1432 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9008kB time=00:00:47.81 bitrate=1543.2kbits/
frame= 1451 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9125kB time=00:00:48.44 bitrate=1543.0kbits/
frame= 1467 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9233kB time=00:00:48.98 bitrate=1544.2kbits/
frame= 1483 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9340kB time=00:00:49.51 bitrate=1545.3kbits/
frame= 1500 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9461kB time=00:00:50.07 bitrate=1547.9kbits/
frame= 1515 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9566kB time=00:00:50.58 bitrate=1549.2kbits/
frame= 1532 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9685kB time=00:00:51.14 bitrate=1551.4kbits/
frame= 1542 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9758kB time=00:00:51.48 bitrate=1552.6kbits/
frame= 1559 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=    9908kB time=00:00:52.04 bitrate=1559.5kbits/
frame= 1577 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10035kB time=00:00:52.62 bitrate=1562.1kbits/
frame= 1593 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10145kB time=00:00:53.18 bitrate=1562.6kbits/
frame= 1609 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10247kB time=00:00:53.71 bitrate=1562.6kbits/
frame= 1627 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10360kB time=00:00:54.32 bitrate=1562.4kbits/
frame= 1645 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10462kB time=00:00:54.92 bitrate=1560.3kbits/
frame= 1664 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10552kB time=00:00:55.55 bitrate=1556.1kbits/
frame= 1681 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10637kB time=00:00:56.10 bitrate=1552.9kbits/
frame= 1699 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10729kB time=00:00:56.71 bitrate=1549.7kbits/
frame= 1716 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10800kB time=00:00:57.29 bitrate=1544.2kbits/
frame= 1733 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10880kB time=00:00:57.85 bitrate=1540.7kbits/
frame= 1752 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   10948kB time=00:00:58.50 bitrate=1533.1kbits/
frame= 1770 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11025kB time=00:00:59.08 bitrate=1528.7kbits/
frame= 1790 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11098kB time=00:00:59.75 bitrate=1521.5kbits/
frame= 1810 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11203kB time=00:01:00.42 bitrate=1518.7kbits/
frame= 1828 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11280kB time=00:01:01.03 bitrate=1514.1kbits/
frame= 1847 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11367kB time=00:01:01.65 bitrate=1510.2kbits/
frame= 1866 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11457kB time=00:01:02.28 bitrate=1506.9kbits/
frame= 1883 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11546kB time=00:01:02.86 bitrate=1504.6kbits/
frame= 1899 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11647kB time=00:01:03.40 bitrate=1504.9kbits/
frame= 1916 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11751kB time=00:01:03.95 bitrate=1505.2kbits/
frame= 1930 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11849kB time=00:01:04.42 bitrate=1506.8kbits/
frame= 1943 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   11949kB time=00:01:04.86 bitrate=1509.2kbits/
frame= 1957 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   12057kB time=00:01:05.32 bitrate=1512.0kbits/
frame= 1973 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   12196kB time=00:01:05.86 bitrate=1516.9kbits/
frame= 1987 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   12305kB time=00:01:06.32 bitrate=1519.8kbits/
frame= 2003 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   12423kB time=00:01:06.86 bitrate=1522.1kbits/
frame= 2018 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   12533kB time=00:01:07.37 bitrate=1523.9kbits/
frame= 2034 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   12651kB time=00:01:07.90 bitrate=1526.2kbits/
frame= 2051 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   12789kB time=00:01:08.46 bitrate=1530.3kbits/
frame= 2066 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   12891kB time=00:01:08.97 bitrate=1531.1kbits/
frame= 2083 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13017kB time=00:01:09.53 bitrate=1533.6kbits/
frame= 2100 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13125kB time=00:01:10.11 bitrate=1533.5kbits/
frame= 2118 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13240kB time=00:01:10.69 bitrate=1534.2kbits/
frame= 2137 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13351kB time=00:01:11.34 bitrate=1533.1kbits/
frame= 2157 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13468kB time=00:01:11.99 bitrate=1532.5kbits/
frame= 2176 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13565kB time=00:01:12.64 bitrate=1529.8kbits/
frame= 2193 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13672kB time=00:01:13.19 bitrate=1530.1kbits/
frame= 2208 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13767kB time=00:01:13.71 bitrate=1530.0kbits/
frame= 2228 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13872kB time=00:01:14.38 bitrate=1527.8kbits/
frame= 2246 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   13976kB time=00:01:14.96 bitrate=1527.3kbits/
frame= 2263 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   14081kB time=00:01:15.54 bitrate=1527.0kbits/
frame= 2281 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   14183kB time=00:01:16.12 bitrate=1526.3kbits/
frame= 2296 fps= 33 q=26.0 size=   14265kB time=00:01:16.63 bitrate=1524.8kbits/
frame= 2313 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=   14400kB time=00:01:17.21 bitrate=1527.8kbits/
frame= 2324 fps= 32 q=-1.0 Lsize=   14851kB time=00:01:17.70 bitrate=1565.7kbits
/s
video:13553kB audio:1215kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB mux
ing overhead: 0.565642%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] frame I:10    Avg QP:23.07  size: 38966
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] frame P:1167  Avg QP:26.28  size:  9096
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] frame B:1147  Avg QP:31.55  size:  2504
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] consecutive B-frames:  2.5% 94.1%  3.1%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] mb I  I16..4:  5.3% 22.2% 72.5%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  1.3%  1.1%  P16..4: 58.5% 16.1%  8.9%
 0.0%  0.0%    skip:13.6%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  B16..8: 54.8%  6.1%  1.8%
 direct: 2.1%  skip:34.9%  L0:51.9% L1:37.5% BI:10.5%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] 8x8 transform intra:41.3% inter:39.6%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 76.5% 70.7% 32.2% inter: 24.0% 17.
6% 2.4%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 31% 38%  8% 22%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 16% 16%  4%  5%  7%  5%
 7%  6%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 34% 22% 12%  4%  5%  6%  6%
 6%  5%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 48% 22% 23%  7%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] ref P L0: 69.6% 21.7%  6.8%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] ref B L0: 91.8%  8.2%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] ref B L1: 99.6%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 03c5d5c0] kb/s:1431.69
```

I checked [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1) and saw no option for it.

Comment: Please include the complete console output from your command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I added the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blurring is happening because you're reencoding the whole video, not because of a faulty subtitle burner.

I'd suggest specifying H.264 as your video codec and at the same time copy the audio track, otherwise ffmpeg will reencode it using libvo_aacenc :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "ass=subtitle.ass" -vcodec libx264 -x264-params crf=18 -preset veryslow -acodec copy out.mp4
```

Feel free to change the crf value to a higher value if the output is too big (x264 default crf that was used in your original command is 23), and the preset to a faster one if the encode is too slow for your taste.

EDIT : I forgot the most important part. Your video is 640x360, so the subtitles are burnt at this resolution. While they will be clean if the video is played at this resolution, they will get blurry once the video is upscaled to your monitor's output. If your monitor is 1080p, that the subs appear blurry is completely normal.

Your last hope is then to upscale the video, there is an example for 720p :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 1280x720 -sws_flags lanczos -vf "ass=subtitle.ass" -vcodec libx264 -x264-params crf=18 -preset veryslow -acodec copy out.mp4
```

This will however generate a bigger file for no quality gain, except on the subs..

Comment: The command -x264-param isn't working. I've to change it to -crf 18, but the burned subtitle result is the same. The video is fine, but the subtitle edges is still blurred, not clear like the softsub. Is it the side effect of burning or because my original video quality isn't high enough?

Comment: See my edit, your video's resolution is most probably what is causing the blurriness once you play the video in fullscreen.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of that before. Thank you.